# Pass html variable to freemarker

Tags: html, input, freemarker

I have an html input hidden variable:

```
 <input type="hidden" id="attachmentPdf" name="attachmentPdf" value="${attachment.mimeType}"/>
```

And I want to pass it to freemarker variable:

```
<#assign x = attachmentPdf.value>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Looks like the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. What is it you really need?

Comment: why don't you just use the `attachment.mimeType`??

Comment: Yes, I need assign to x variable my attachment.mimeType parameter, but when I tried something like this: <#assign x=attachment.mimeType> or <#assign x=${attachment.mimeType}> I didn't get what I want.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you found a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

This looks impossible to me, FreeMarker is a server side language and will not feed anything back to the server, so basically imagine it as a one way street from server to client, but not the other way around. It's possible, but you need custom FreeMarker directives to communicate with a REST API that would allow POST requests to do things like receive an uploaded pdf...